# Qt file size limit

Tags: qt

I know how to **read** | **write** | **open** files **in Qt**. What am I trying to achieve is this; How do I create a new file when the ***existing file exceeds 'x' size***? For instance, I have a 100KB file size, before writing to the same file, check the size, if size exceed 100KB, create a new one (not removing the existing one), chmod it if needed, then keep on writing.

I tried this:

```
QString filename("W:/file.txt");
    QFile file(filename);
    QFileInfo info(file);
    int size = 0;
    if (file.open(QIODevice::ReadWrite | QIODevice::Truncate))
    {
        QTextStream stream(&file);
        while(size < 102400) {
            stream << "something" << endl;
            size += info.size();
        }
    }
    qDebug() << info.size();
```

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! Please check the [FAQ - How do I ask a good question?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) on how to ask good questions, so that you get good answers. At least, you should have tried something yourself, and ideally show some **code** of what you have tried. Hint: check out http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-5.1/qtcore/qfileinfo.html

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this [QFileInfo::size()](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-5.1/qtcore/qfileinfo.html#size) return file size in bytes.